# Unable to generate list based on string array which is inside class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below is my class and code:

```
public class Properties
{
    public string Prop1;
    public string[] Prop2;
}

public IEnumerable<Properties> GetProperties()
{
    string [] props = new[] { "abc", "xyz", };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        yield return new Properties { Prop1 = "Prop" + i, Prop2 = props};
    }
}

var values = GetProperties().Select(x => new {
                      prop = x.Prop2.ToString()
                 }).ToList();
```

Now I want my values variable to contains list of props but here i am getting props as array but I want it as single string.

Expected Output:

```
Values[0] : Name : abc
Values[1] : Name : xyz
```

How can I do this with linq?

Comment: doing somthing like: public IEnumerable<Properties> GetProperties()
  {
           List<string>  props = List<string> { "abc", "xyz", };
        
   return props.Select(xx=> new Properties { Prop1 = xx, Prop2 = props })
  }

Comment: What do you mean by "expected output"? Your posted code is a bit of a mess and it seems like you are doing a lot of unnecessary work here. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. You already have a class definition - why do you need to project it into an anonymous type?

Comment: @TheAnathema:Because i need to return this output to my web service which expects this format

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Properties
{
    public string Prop1;
    public string[] Prop2;
}

public List<Properties> GetProperties()
{
        var list = new List<Properties>();
        var props = new[] { "abc", "xyz", }.toList();
        props.ForEach(p=>{
            var np = new Properties { Prop1 = "Prop" + i, Prop2 = props};
            list.Add(np);
        });
        return list;
}

var values = GetProperties().Select(x => new {
                    prop = x.Prop2.ToString()
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this output you wrote for all 4 values, you should use `SelectMany`:

```
var values = GetProperties().SelectMany(x => x.Prop2).ToList();
```

if you want to have exact output you wrote, you should take only the first value of `GetProperties()` and you don't need any `Select`:

```
var values = GetProperties().First().Prop2;
```